# Create back button for Phonegap ios apps using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new for developing iOS apps How to set setup native back button using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

When you override backbutton, you also prevent its original behavior. So user can't close app with it. You must use

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

To bring original behavior back.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear. But i assume you need a native type back button in your application.

Try exploring this [plugin](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-navigationbar-plugin),

If you are new to cordova(previously phonegap) IOS, look for `how to use native plugins` with phonegap.

Note that Different plugins may require different configurations(way of using them), In most cases you will find the steps on the plugin page.

Also using plugins will be version dependent. So make sure you are using the plugin which is compatible with your cordova version

You can also get the back button functionality using javascript as commented out in other answer.
Just make sure you over-ride the function after device ready.

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}


function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown(){
     console.log("put your code for back button here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
window.history.back();
```